# Establecer addActionListener a un JMenuBar mediante MVC

Tags: java, mvc, jmenubar

Estoy haciendo un programa en forma mvc (que he aprendido), el cual tiene tres paquetes. En el paquete vista tengo el JFrame que integra un JMenuBar. En el paquete modelo tengo los datos y lógica. Y mediante el paquete controlador interrelaciono el paquete vista con el paquete modelo.

```
public class Marco_base extends JFrame{
private MenuBar_base menuBar;    

public Marco_base(){
    super();
    setTitle("MARCO INICIO");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    
    //Set menuBar
    menuBar=new MenuBar_base();     
    setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    //Set panel de contenido
    contentPane=(JPanel)this.getContentPane();
    //set layout
    contentPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentPane,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));       
    //Set color fondo marco (panel)
    contentPane.setOpaque(true);
    contentPane.setBackground(Color.PINK);
    //Set borde marco
    Border border=BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20,20,20,20);
    //contentPane.setBorder(border);
    //Añadir componentes
    addComponents();
       
    //Propiedades del marco
    pack();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

}

```
public class MenuBar_base extends JMenuBar{
private JMenu file, edit;
private JMenuItem nuevaSala, nuevaPelicula;

public MenuBar_base(){
    createMenuBar();
}

public void createMenuBar(){
    
    file=new JMenu("File");
    
    nuevaSala=new JMenuItem("Nueva Sala");
    file.add(nuevaSala);
    nuevaPelicula=new JMenuItem("Nueva Película");
    file.add(nuevaPelicula);
    
    edit=new JMenu("Edit");
           
    add(file);
    add(edit);
}

public JMenu getFile() {
    return file;
}

public JMenuItem getNuevaSala() {
    return nuevaSala;
}

public JMenuItem getNuevaPelicula() {
    return nuevaPelicula;
}
```

}

```
public class ActionControlador implements ActionListener{

public ActionControlador(Marco_base objM,SalaDao objSdao,SalaValidador objSV) {
    super(objM,objSdao,objSV);
    actionListener(this);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JMenuItem source = (JMenuItem)(e.getSource());
    if(getObjM().getMenuBar().getMenu(0).getItem(0).equals(source)){
        
    }
}

public void actionListener(ActionListener listener){
    getObjM().getMenuBar().getMenu(1).getItem(1).addActionListener(listener);
```

}}

Aquí hay algunos puntos que no acabo de entender. El primero que en la clase Marco_base no puedo crear un getter de MenuBar_base ya que no sobreescribe el getMenuBar del Jframe.Esto lo puedo entender pero creo que es la base de mi problema.
Pero el problema lo tengo en el método actionListener de la clase ActionControlador que me marca NullPointerEXCEPTION. Aquí es donde tengo el problema principal porque yo generalmente sustituía dicho codigo por: getObjM().getMenuBar().getNuevaSala().addActionListener(listener);

Entonces algo estoy hciendo mal. Haber si me echais una mano.
Gracias de antemano. Un saludo.

Comment: No hagais caso al error de los parámetros que indican 1 y 0. Imaginemos que son todo 0.

Answer (score 0):

Ya he conseguido la solución. Consistía en sustituir el método `getMenuBar()` por `getJMenuBar()`.